# UIPageController inside UINavigationController is offset from the top?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

This a little bit wierd i have made `UIPageController` that works and everything is fine. But when i put it inside `UINavigationController`, it offset from the for status bar. Than i swipe up on that screen it positions itself right and everything is ok. I don't really understand what is happening. Here are the images[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe try setting `adjustScrollViewInsets` to false on UIPageController

Comment: that is such a random thing apple... thank you that solves it, put it as an answer so i can accept it. Also elaborate little if you will

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try setting `adjustScrollViewInsets` to false on UIPageController.

This is the property that determines whether the system should automatically add inset to a UIScrollView in your view controller's view hierarchy when it is being displayed behind transparent bars (here , the navigation bar). What happened here is that the system assumed the bounds of the page controller overlaps with that of the nav bar and so it adds insets so that the view's contents is fully visible and is not obscured by the nav bar. But in this case it is wrong since it seems your page controller's bounds starts at the bottom edge of the nav bar.

I think you can also set the nav bar as opaque to disable the automatic adding of insets.